# Starting an activity from an onClick class

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a button which I am assigning an `OnClickListener` to. I want to start a new intent as a result of this. In order to do that, I have to reference the activity. The only one I know how to do this is via something like the following code. Is this the best way to start an intent from a button click? Also, what kind of memory implications will there be for this?

```
public class SomeActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    private final FragmentActivity self=this;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.startButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(self,someClass.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the variable `self` replacing it by `someActivity.this`. By the way, you should start names of your class by a capital letter (`SomeActivity` instead of `someActivity`). Except things said above, your code is right.

Comment: Wow, that was simple... Sigh. Wonder if it'll improve my memory usage any. Thanks! Post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @yDelouis he was probably overriding his real activity names with camelCase, maybe to go faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to simply pass `ActtivityName.this`, like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.startButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(SomeActivity.this,someClass.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this will be calling : 
`findViewById(R.id.startButton).setOnClickListener(this);`
Then make your `Activity` implement `View.OnClickListener` and implement the methods `onClick(View v)` in this way :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.startButton:
            Intent intent=new Intent(self,someClass.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        // Handle click on other views

    }
}
```

It prevents from instantiating a listener and should be a bit better for memory consumption.

Comment: The memory efficiency here is very likely trivial. Also, this approach makes it more difficult to add separate listeners for multiple buttons. Personally, I prefer using anonymous classes for listeners.

Comment: I agree, I liked your comment better.